# React Router Dom v6 - element with parameters drives me to functions are not valid as a react child

Tags: reactjs, routes, element

I know there is a lot of posts on this topic but i havent found one with elements passed as parameters and i dont know how to do it without declaring a function.

I dont understand why react tells me this error as i thought it was only saying this when the react component invoked does not contain react component structure/elements/requirements.

My MainComponent.js code is as follow: (i'm passing parameters to the route /menu/:dishId with a const DishWithId)

```
import {Navbar,NavbarBrand} from 'reactstrap';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import {DISHES} from '../shared/dishes'
import Dishdetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import Contact from './ContactComponent'
import {Routes,Route,Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './HeaderComponent'
import {COMMENTS} from '../shared/comments';
import {LEADERS} from '../shared/leaders';
import {PROMOTIONS} from '../shared/promotions';
class Main extends Component {
  constructor (props){
    super (props);
    this.state = {dishes: DISHES, comments: COMMENTS, promotions: PROMOTIONS, leaders: LEADERS};
  }


  render(){
    const shouldRedirect=true;

    const HomePage=()=>{
    return (
        <Home dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish)=>dish.featured)[0]}
              promotion={this.state.promotions.filter((promotion)=>promotion.featured)[0]}
              leader={this.state.leaders.filter((leader)=>leader.featured)[0]}
        />
    );
  }
  const DishWithId=({match})=>{

      return (
          <Dishdetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === parseInt(match.params.dishId, 10))[0]}
                      comments={this.state.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(match.params.dishId, 10)[0])}/>

      );
    
    }

  return (<div className="App">
    <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/menu' element={<Menu dishes={this.state.dishes}/> }/>
        <Route path="/menu/:dishId" element={DishWithId}/>
        <Route path='/home' element={<HomePage/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/contactus' element={<Contact/>}/>
        <Route path='/' element={
            shouldRedirect ? (<Navigate replace to="/home" />) : (<HomePage />)
          }/>
      </Routes>

    <Footer/>

  </div>);
}
}
export default Main;
```

I get the error when i go to http://localhost:3000/menu/0

I tried to use render() but i didnt manage to make it work.
Note this code was supposed to work with previous version of react where component was in place of element (it comes from a mooc)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change the route

```
<Route path="/menu/:dishId" element={DishWithId}/>
```

To:

```
<Route path="/menu/:dishId" element={<DishWithId />}/>
```

And update your `DishWithId` to use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams) hook for getting the `dishId`, like:

```
const DishWithId=({match})=>{
  const { dishId } = useParams()

  return (
      <Dishdetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === parseInt(dishId, 10))[0]}
                  comments={this.state.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(dishId, 10)[0])}/>

  );

}
```